# Why didn't the Mandalorians post a sentry to guard their camp?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-mandalorian

Has any canon explanation been given as to why the Mandalorians did not post a sentry during S3 E1 "The Apostate" and S3 E4 "The Foundling", thus allowing themselves to be attacked by several large predators that should have been easily spotted at a distance given their advanced technology and intense training?

For example, is it part of their custom, or due to low numbers?

Comment: It's actually noted that the predator who attacked them in "The Foundling" had attacked them several times previously, and we can see the helmet of at least one of its prior victims in its nest when they go to rescue Ragnar, which makes it all the more galling that they don't have anyone on lookout in case it attacks again.

Comment: I'm sure the Armorer's reply would be something like "Does beskar keep watch against being struck by the smith's hammer?"